# Finding minifigs in a specific theme

Tags: minifigures, shopping

A couple of times I've been asked by people what is the cheapest or easiest way to buy some random complete minifigs in some theme.
For example:

- they have a couple of fairground sets and they want to create a diorama populated with minifigures is summer/leisure attire...
- they have a winter village they want to populate with minifigs that are warmly dressed...
- they have a shopping mall or business district, they want minifigs in more formal attire...
- some workers on a construction site...

They usually don't want to spend the time picking out individual minifig elements, just some random complete figs with some restrictions on their attire and preferably as cheap as possible.

What would you recommend to these people?

Answer (score 3):

Where I live, Brisbane Australia, we have [BrickResales](https://brickresales.com.au/) online as well as an actual shop. They often sell packets with six or eight minifigs relating to a theme. I've purchased half a dozen construction workers in one lot, for example. Have a look in your area for similar.

Answer (score 3):

BrickLink has minifigures [broken out by category](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=M) and many people sell them this way because often the minifigs are the most valuable part of a set.  The biggest problem I foresee in using this method is that the categories might not line up with what you are looking for very well.  You might need to search through a few categories to find all of the options.